# Codeigniter GET parameters not passing via url

Tags: codeigniter, get

I am trying to implement the logout procedure for my website.
When the user clicks the sign out button I redirect him to the following `home` controller script.

```
http : // mydomain/php/ci/index.php/index/?logout=set
```

And in my home controller `index` function I check if logout=set then destroy all sessions.

```
    echo @$_GET['logout'];
    exit();
    if(@$_GET['logout'] == "set")
    {
        unset($_SESSION['userid']);
        @$_SESSION = array();
        @session_unset();
        @session_destroy();
    }
```

But when I reach here nothing gets printed because the logout param is not passing.
I see the following url when i get here on clicking the sign out button.

```
http://localhost/php/ci/home/
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: why the hell you set @ before the $_GET ??? > @$_GET['logout'];

Comment: because when the user visits the page when he's not logged in it gives me an error that the variable is not set.So for the first time the variable will not be set.But when user will log out the variable will be set.That's why I used it to ignore this `variable not set error`

Comment: Well you certainly don't need the `@` at the beginning of the last 3 lines. Note that `$_GET` parameters were disabled by default before CodeIgniter 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the `get` data with `CodeIgniter` like this:

```
var_dump($this->input->get());
```

However, don't use the `index` method to log users out, but make a method for it, like i.e. this:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller() {
    public function index() {
        // Index stuff here        
    }

    public function logout() {
        // Your check if a user is logged in, instead of the dirty @
        if(isSet($_SESSION['userid'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['userid']);
        }

        redirect();
    }
}
```

Then in your view make a link like this:

```
site_url("users/logout");
```

You will want to use the CodeIgniter session handler for this, but this is just a quick solution for your problem. I can advice you to read the CodeIgniter manual. As your "solution" for logging out is quite dirty and does not fit the MVC principle

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has deafault INPUT class which is loaded.. 
Check it.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/input.html